# "Be in a dilemma" vs. "have a dilemma"

Tags: grammaticality

What is the correct form? "We have been in a dilemma" or "We have had a dilemma"? Or are the two of them incorrect? I'm a non-native English speaker discussing this with another non-native speaker.

Comment: Why is the question being downvoted? I just read the FAQ and I see nothing wrong with the question. An explanation would be useful.

Comment: Don't know about downvote.  Keep in mind that phrases like  “Thank you in advance” should not be included.  Do you know about http://ell.stackexchange.com/ for 
English Language Learners?

Comment: Perhaps the downvotes reflect the lack of research.

Comment: When I have this type of questions I google the expressions and check how many results each return. In this case it was not conclusive, therefore my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A dilemma describes a position of doubt in which two (occasionally more) choices are available. It's not something you have, but something you're **in**.

Comment: "We have a dilemma" or "we had a dilemma" is perfectly fine. But "we have had a dilemma" seems to me to be an incorrect use of the perfect tense for some reason (I have no clue why), with "we have been in a dilemma" the proper alternative.

Comment: @Peter Shor. With all the usual cautions about corpus searches, there are 60 records for _in a dilemma_ in the COCA and 18 for _have a dilemma_. The figures for the BNC are 24 and 3. The OED has 12 citations for _in a dilemma_ and none for _have a dilemma_.

Comment: That may be the original usage, but soemoen faces with a difficult choice is often described as having  a dilemma, and I think that usage is perfectly acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

One also sees: *[He is on the horns of a dilemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilemma)*.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on [GEdgar's reply](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/105654/16510),

In [Odysseus' idiomatic dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Between_Scylla_and_Charybdis) he had to choose between one of two courses for his ship, embodied in two ravenous monsters: [Scylla](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Scylla) and [Charybdis](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Charybdis). That's where the horns come from, it seems.